# Two windows in one WPF app

Tags: wpf, vb.net, windows

WPF & VB.NET

I have an app with two separate windows. One window for Login and the next is the main app window...

when i click login Verify button, if credentials are correct, then login window should close and main app window should open.
for that i coded,

```
Private Sub Verify_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Verify.Click
    Dim Home As New MainWindow()
    Home.Show()
    Application.Current.MainWindow = Home
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Home => Main App window

Me => Login window

initially this worked. But now it shows an exception

A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

```
Additional information: 'Add value to collection of type System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' threw an exception.
```

Both windows have this style:

```
WindowStyle="None"
ResizeMode="NoResize"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
WindowState="Maximized"
AllowsTransparency="True"
```

Kindly guide through...

Comment: Your XAML of the second window is wrong. Find out whats wrong and fix it.

Comment: Yes i tried it works. but when i run the second window individually there is no error in xaml.

Comment: The exception prbably gave you a line number somewhere.

Comment: yes line 112 position 10

Comment: Can you please edit the question and point/paste the line which is causing this problem !!!

Comment: Yes i found it. thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

For Login window,
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" is ok.

Main window, remove WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen".

Make this change and it should work

Comment: The position won't cause an exception.